# How to send Node js mail from Nodemailer i gor error in nodemailer

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

How can i send mail from node js with the use of my domail mail like as : noreply@example.com

The connection setting was below using nodemailer

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'https://example.com',
        port: 465, // Port
        secure: true, // this is true as port is 465
        auth: {
        user: 'noreply@example.com',
        pass: 'mypassword'
        }
    });
```

If i send mail there is an error like below

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://example.com
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26) {
   errno: -3008,
   code: 'EDNS',
   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
   hostname: 'https://example.com',
   command: 'CONN'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when I accedentally added a trailing space to the hostname. The problem seems to be the failing DNS lookup.

In your example: The `https://` part is not part of the hostname. In fact, you use SMTP protocol, not https.

try

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'example.com', // Whatever your true hostname is. Could also be smtp.example.com or similar.
    port: 465, // Port
    secure: true, // this is true as port is 465
    auth: {
    user: 'noreply@example.com',
    pass: 'mypassword'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might come from your SMTP.
check your configuration correct or wrong by using (outlook or google mail).